# How does the Json response know/remembers who requested it?

Tags: json

For instance, say I'm trying to communicate with another app that randomizes any string. If **user1** sends a Json request and then **user2** also sends a Json request, how does the Json responses know which user to associate itself with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is handled at the network layer between the client and the server unless user 1 and 2 are sharing the same client.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. So the client (the actual computer/session) is really the only thing interacting with the api? Sorry, but could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Assuming for a moment that we're discussing a web api, the request is made via HTTP which is an application level protocol on top of the IP suite (TCP/UDP). When the request is sent the client computer negotiates a connection with the server so the server knows to which computer to send the response.